# Google PlayService Version Issue

Tags: android, google-play

Actually i was using some older version of Google playservice library in my project, for one new library integration it needs new version of the google play service library. i have update the playservice , taken and integrated the google play newer version but when i am running the project dex error is coming. can any one sort this out. Thank in advance......

Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

at the same time if i use older version its running properly.

Comment: which is your working environment... Eclipse or Android studio??

Comment: You exceeded the multidex limit

Comment: @user2806221 Man why are you still using eclipse :)

Comment: @user2806221 Moving to Android studio is the best option here.

If you don't want to move to studio at this moment, you can do one workaround. You have to identify the unused methods in your jar file say,google play service jar file(In fact, most may be unused) and remove that. After removing those methods, create new jar file and replace the old one. But I recommend you to move to Android Studio as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The version added more methods, and you probably included the entire play services as a dependency, thus exceeding the multidex limit of about 65K methods and therefore the error.

You are welcome to [read more about including only the dependencies you really use](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split).

For example, do you really need Google Maps, Google Wallet, Google Fit, Google Auth, and Google Cloud Messaging all in your app? The answer is probably not unless you are making some type of sports app with Google login features and you can buy stuff.